# GitHub workflow user/repository

Tags: github, workflow

Firebase deploy Error:
firebase init hosting:github, 404 error if the repo belongs
For which GitHub repository would you like to set up a GitHub workflow? (format: user/repository)

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qUVW.png) Just type your GitHub username/repository and press enter.

That's all.

This worked for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qUVW.png)

[2] See my answer in the picture, I uploaded. This will help you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand most of people who have issue with this , know what it says just that steps are not clear .like :

1. Will it create new repo?
   -> No.
2. Do I have create new repo?
   -> Yes.
3. Why isn't it creating new repo like normal GitHub function?
   -> Because its firebase not ***github init***

So:

1. create new repository by going to GitHub Web Page
   https://github.com/.
2. Copy the repository name
3. Type your GitHub /<new/old repository name> and press
   enter.

I had same issue but no clear answer , because normally GitHub creates repo in cli when initializing.

I hope this is clear enough, and was able to help.